# Importing XML data with a namespace into SQL Server

Tags: sql, xml, import, namespaces

I have an XML document containing data that I want to import into existing SQL server tables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<geia:GEIA-STD-0007 xmlns:geia="http://www.geia_STD_0007.com/2006/schema" xmlns:xsi=`enter code here`"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<geia:full_file>
<geia:XA_end_item_acronym_code_data>
<geia:end_item_acronym_code>ON565</geia:end_item_acronym_code>
<geia:logistics_support_analysis_control_number_structure>32222222</geia:logistics_support_analysis_control_number_structure>
</geia:XA_end_item_acronym_code_data>
<geia:XB_logistics_support_analysis_control_number_indentured_item_data>
<geia:end_item_acronym_code>ON565</geia:end_item_acronym_code>
<geia:logistics_support_analysis_control_number>E2C06CAAE</geia:logistics_support_analysis_control_number>
<geia:alternate_logistics_support_analysis_control_number_code>06</geia:alternate_logistics_support_analysis_control_number_code>
<geia:logistics_support_analysis_control_number_type>P</geia:logistics_support_analysis_control_number_type>
<geia:logistics_support_analysis_control_number_nomenclature>CABLE ASSEMBLY W5</geia:logistics_support_analysis_control_number_nomenclature>
<geia:reliability_availability_and_maintainability_indicator>Y</geia:reliability_availability_and_maintainability_indicator>
<geia:system_end_item_identifier>N</geia:system_end_item_identifier>
<geia:technical_manual_functional_group_code>41JE150</geia:technical_manual_functional_group_code>
</geia:XB_logistics_support_analysis_control_number_indentured_item_data>
<geia:XB_logistics_support_analysis_control_number_indentured_item_data>
<geia:end_item_acronym_code>ON565</geia:end_item_acronym_code>
<geia:logistics_support_analysis_control_number>E2C06CAAMZZ</geia:logistics_support_analysis_control_number>
<geia:alternate_logistics_support_analysis_control_number_code>06</geia:alternate_logistics_support_analysis_control_number_code>
<geia:logistics_support_analysis_control_number_type>P</geia:logistics_support_analysis_control_number_type>
<geia:logistics_support_analysis_control_number_nomenclature>CONSUMABLES</geia:logistics_support_analysis_control_number_nomenclature>
<geia:system_end_item_identifier>N</geia:system_end_item_identifier>
</geia:XB_logistics_support_analysis_control_number_indentured_item_data>
</geia:full_file>
</geia:GEIA-STD-0007>
```

I have been looking online for code that can help me accomplish this task but have not had much luck.  So far this is the code I have been trying to use:

```
----step 1 Import XML data from an XML file into SQL Server table using the OPENROWSET function

drop table lsa.XMLwithOpenXML

CREATE TABLE lsa.XMLwithOpenXML
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO lsa.XMLwithOpenXML(XMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\Temp\e2c.xml', SINGLE_CLOB) AS x;


--SELECT * FROM lsa.XMLwithOpenXML

--get xmldata to shred
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Declare @xmlData as xml
Select @xmlData =  XMLData FROM lsa.XMLwithOpenXML
------------------------------------------------------------

--create variable to hold the int id of the xmldoc created by the sp
DECLARE @XMLdocId AS INT

--procedureName, outputId, InputData
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @XMLdocId OUTPUT, @xmlData , '<geia:GEIA-STD-0007 xmlns:geia="http://www.geia_STD_0007.com/2006/schema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">'

--create an OenXML query to shred the doc, or transfer it into rowsets
INSERT INTO [lsa].[XB]
           (
           [end_item_acronym_code])
Select end_item_acronym_code from 
OpenXML(@XMLdocId, '/geia:XB_logistics_support_analysis_control_number_indentured_item_data',2)
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('xmlns:geia="http://www.geia_STD_0007.com/2006/schema' AS geia, DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' )
SELECT 
    x.c( '.' )  AS result

FROM @xmlData.nodes('geia:GEIA-STD-0007/geia:full_file/geia:XB_logistics_support_analysis_control_number_indentured_item_data') x(c)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @XMLdocId
```

I realize that this code is very wrong.  The path that I am passing to the OpenXML() function is wrong, but I have tried many iterations of it and none have been successful. I am also not 100% certain how to go about pulling out the different table data (ie XA, XB) but my plan is to pull from one table then reiterate the code for each additional table. This code will be used to import large amounts of data (I only posted a part of the xml file) with many different tables. If anyone has a better idea, then I would welcome it, as I am still learning.